# Cambiar valor de campo en trigger

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla en la que al cambiar el campo condición me permite guardar en una tabla histórico dicho campo.

El `trigger` que hace eso es este:

```sql
BEGIN
    IF OLD.condicion <> new.condicion THEN
        INSERT INTO t_historico (cod, campo, old_valor, new_valor)
        VALUES(old.cod, 'CONDICION', old.condicion, new.condicion);
    END IF;
END
```

El campo 'condicion' es numérico, pero lo que quiero es cambiar ese valor por una descripción según este detalle:

1. PENDIENTE
2. ACTIVO
3. INACTIVO
4. SUSPENSO

Es decir, que mi tabla `historico` no va a guardar los números, sino los textos correspondientes en los campos `old_valor` y `new_valor`.

¿Alguna idea para resolver esto?

Comment: Como pretendes guardar strings en un campo numerico?

Comment: Otra opción sería una tabla tipo "descripcioncondiciones" en la que asocies id 1 = 'Pendiente', 2='Activo'... etc. Y cuando muestres resultados hacer un JOIN y listo. Me refiero a si no puedes cambiar la estructura de la tabla original, que como dice @adrigo es la única solución si quieres guardar STRINGs en un campo Numérico

Comment: *El campo `condicion` es numérico pero lo que quiero es cambiar ese valor por una descripción...* No es una buena idea lo que intentas hacer, déjalo como numérico e incorpora la descripción de forma independiente, sea mediante una tabla que asocie cada valor numérico a la descripción, sea en la lógica del programa.

Comment: Cierto! no me había percatado de ese detalle. Tendré que hacer una consulta para relacionar la descripción con los valores del campo `condicion`.

Comment: Por cierto, y ahora qué pasa con la pregunta? se cierra? se queda?